# Access class scope within static function ES6

Tags: javascript, es6-class

How does one access `this` scope with a static function of a class? Am I missing something here?

```
class Example {

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Johan';
  }

  static hello(){

    // How to access `this` scope here in the static

    Example.name; // Undefined
    this.name; // Undefined
  }

}
```

Comment: `this` in `hello` is the class itself

Comment: The premise here is flawed - You are setting `this.name` in an instance of a class, which static methods inherently do not have.

Comment: I understand this but accessing `this.name` using `Example.name` renders undefined.

Comment: `name` is an instance variable. To access it, you must create an instance (in the static method). `Example.name` implies that `name` is a static member of the class, which clearly it isn't.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this?

Comment: Why do you think that `hello` should be `static` ?!

Comment: I don't. Ideally for my current use case the static function needs access to the scope, as another class calls the static function.

Comment: You have 2 options: _Don't call it statically_ or _Don't use "this" scope_. You can't have both.

Answer (score 1):

The commenters are correct, `this` in the context of a static class method is the class itself.

When you create an *instance* of the class using `new`, *that instance* is its own `this`.  You can access properties and methods on the instance through `this`.

See the examples below:

```js
class Example {

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Johan';
  }

  static hello(){
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.name);
  }

}

Example.hello();  // logs out the above class definition, followed by the name of the class itself.

let x = new Example();
console.log(x.name);  // logs out 'Johan'.

x.hello(); // x does not have `hello()`.  Only Example does.
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to run this instance within the static function of the class not outside. Is this possible? Meaning within `static hello()` I need access to `this.name` without acquiring it outside of the class.

Comment: @Nicos: What you want doesn't make sense. If you call a method statically there is no instance, so there is no `this`. Javascript can't figure out for you which instance of the class was expected.

So instead of hacking your way around this, try to figure out *why* you want to do this and then try to fix your issue in a different way that doesn't require this hack.

Comment: Thank you, that's all I wanted to know.

Comment: "*this in the context of a static class method is…*", no, not  the class **prototype** itself.